# How to find the "through" associated object in has_many_through relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What's the easiest way to find the 'middle' association in has_many :through association?

What I mean is, I have 3 models:

```
class VoiceActor < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :characters
  has_many :shows, through: :characters
end
```

```
class Character < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :shows
  belongs_to :voice_actor, optional: true
end
```

```
class Show < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :characters
  has_many :voice_actors, through: :characters

  def character(voice_actor_id)
    self.characters.find_by(voice_actor_id: voice_actor_id)
  end
end
```

What I want to is, on a view page for a voice actor to display all shows they appear in. and next to each of those shows, show what character is played by them

I did get it to work, but I'm unsure if my solution is ok? Seems bit heavy on the view still. What I currently do is I pass @voice_actor to the view and @shows (which is just @voice_actor.shows) and use the character method defined in my show model as seen above

and then do

```
Appears in:
<ul>
  <% @shows.each do |show| %>
    <li>
      <%= link_to show.name, show %> as <%= link_to show.character(@voice_actor.id).name, show.character(@voice_actor.id)  %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

would you say that's an okay solution or is there a more elegant way about it? I'm especially worried that I might be doing some bad practice regarding logic in the view

Answer (score 0):

I would model the domain differently and avoid `has_and_belongs_to_many`. Instead create an actual model that represents the job an actor does in a show:

```ruby
class Casting < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :character
  belongs_to :voice_actor
  belongs_to :show
end

class VoiceActor < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :castings
  has_many :shows, through: :castings
  has_many :characters, through: :castings
end

class Character < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :castings
  has_many :shows, though: :castings
  has_many :voice_actors, though: :castings
end

class Show < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :castings
  has_many :characters, through: :castings
  has_many :voice_actors, through: :castings
end
```

This provides the flexibilty so that a character (say for example Batman) can be played by different actors and occur in different shows.

Then when you want to list the roles that an actor has played you would do it looping through this model:

```
Appears in:
<ul>
  <% @actor.castings.each do |casting| %>
    <li>
      <%= link_to(casting.show.name, show) %> as <%= link_to(casting.character.name, casting.character) %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Unlike your solution which causes a N+1 query this can be eager loaded:

```rb
@actor = Actor.eager_load(castings: [:show, :character])
              .find(params[:id])
```

Comment: Its also possible that you could do a separate join table between shows and characters instead of having three foreign keys.